# What are the biggest and smallest represent-able numbers with single precision floating points?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to understand the limits of the floating point representation.

On a 32-bit computer with 7 bits for the exponent and 24 bits for the mantissa, I want to know the biggest and smallest numbers.

My calculation:

**Base 2**

Biggest positive number = 
$$
+ 1 \times 2^{127}
$$

Smallest positive number =
$$
+ 2^{-24} \times 2^{-127}
$$

Biggest negative number = $$
- 2^{-24} \times 2^{-127}
$$

Smallest negative number =  $$-1 \times 2^{127}$$

**Decimal**

Biggest positive number = 
$$
+1 \times 10^{38}
$$

Smallest positive number=
$$
+ 10^{-7} \times 10^{-38}
$$

Biggest negative number=
$$
- 10^{-7} \times 10^{-38}
$$

Smallest negative number = 
$$
-1 \times 10^{38}
$$

Is this a correct calculation?

Comment: Also consider subnormal numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number/53203428#53203428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation varies a bit from the [IEEE standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision), but the Wikipedia page gives explicit calculations for binary.  There are details about the offset in the exponent and whether the leading 1 is suppressed in the mantissa that need to be considered before you get a final answer.  But their range is about 1.18 E-38 to 3.4 E38 and with one bit less in the exponent you should have a range of about 1.18 E-19 to 3.4 E19.

For the base 10 case you need to specify how the base 10 numbers are stored for a clean answer.  Added:  it looks like your base 10 numbers are approximately the decimal equivalents of the binary.  I hadn't noticed and thought you were storing values somehow in base 10.

Answer (score 0):

All current CPUs store floating point in binary, therefore you can get the decimal ranges by mere base conversion. I don't know what is your background, but keep in mind that there is loss of precision when numbers with different exponents are involved in an operation, see [epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Comment: More to the point: in inexact arithmetic, there exist *representable* numbers $\eta$ such that $x+\eta=x$ for any $x$, and for $x=1$, machine $\epsilon$ is the largest such $\eta$.

Comment: The OP has given a calculation that shows that he clearly understands that. He wants to know if his results are correct.

Comment: He's give results in decimal separately; which indicated to me he did not understand how numbers are stored in computers.